# X11 ssh forwarding channel 0

Tags: ssh, xorg, redhat-enterprise-linux

The following options is set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

ForwardX11 yes

ForwardAgent yes

ForwardX11Trusted yes

export $DISPLAY :0.0

echo $DISPLAY

:0.0

$ ssh root@server ip address

pw

X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

please explain how to configure x11

cannot restart sshd after editing

Already xorg is available in redhat7.
library@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | grep -i xorg

xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.2-22.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-vmware-13.0.2-7.20150211git8f0cf7c.el7.x86_64 abrt-addon-xorg-2.1.11-45.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-ati-7.6.1-3.20160215gitd41fccc.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-xkb-utils-7.7-12.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-20.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1.0.11-4.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-14.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-xinit-1.3.4-1.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-vesa-2.3.2-20.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.8.2-1.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch xorg-x11-server-common-1.17.2-22.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-dummy-0.3.6-21.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drivers-7.7-6.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-wacom-0.29.0-1.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-fbdev-0.4.3-20.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-qxl-0.1.1-18.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-v4l-0.2.0-42.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-evdev-2.9.2-2.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-vmmouse-13.0.0-12.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-utils-7.5-14.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-void-1.4.1-1.el7.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.917-22.20151206.el7.x86_64 [library@localhost ~]$

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned options belong to the `ssh_config`, not the `sshd_config`. You should add them to the client, not to the server!

Comment: Please explain how to do it

Comment: not to the root?

Comment: Open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, remove these options you wrote there. Open `~/.ssh/config` and add them here.

Comment: using it as normal user?.

Comment: normal user can not write in `/etc/`, but the `~/.ssh/config` should be written as a user you are going to use.